# Change image's src attribute based on JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Here is the div:

```
<div id="img-container">
  <img id="upSlika" src="#"/>
</div>
```

And this is the JSON response:

```
{"pictureUrl":"url"}
```

How can I change image's source to URL received in response above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that your json is stored in the following variable `json`:

```
var json = {"pictureUrl": "url"};
```

With the following code, what you do is to set the attribute `src` to the element `img` with `id="upSlika"`:

```
$("#upSlika").attr("src", json.pictureUrl);
```

You can check the documentation [jQuery ID Selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and [jQuery .attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the image's src in jQuery by using `attr()` function.
See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Try the code bellow:

```
//get the json to data variable
var data = {"pictureUrl":"url"};

$("#upSlika").attr("src", data.pictureUrl);
```